# How add translation to "name" fields in my array codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have array in codeigniter code how add translation in same line for name fields

```
        $ret = array(
        array(
            'y' => $open_projects,
            'name' => 'Open jobs',
            'color' => '#fc0',
        ),
        array(
            'y' => $completed_projects,
            'name' => 'Completed jobs',
            'color' => '#0c0',
        ),
        array(
            'y' => $active_projects,
            'name' => 'Processing jobs',
            'color' => '#f06',
        ),
        array(
            'y' => $cnl_projects,
            'name' => 'Cancelled jobs',
            'color' => '#0cf',
        ),
    );
```

i have lang key  folder dashboard_lang.php in language root :

application\language\arabic\dashboard_lang.php

```
$lang['myprofile_emp_open_jobs_emp']='open project';
```

this display code

```
<li><i class="zmdi zmdi-label"></i><?php echo $v['name'] ?> : <?php echo $v['y'] ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you load the `lang()` function:

```
$this->load->helper('language');
```

Then you load the language file:

```
$this->lang->load('dashboard_lang', 'arabic');
```

And then you can get the translation with `lang()`:

```
        array(
            'y' => $open_projects,
            'name' => lang('myprofile_emp_open_jobs_emp'),
            'color' => '#fc0',
        ),
```

**Useful links:**

Language Class documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/language.html

Language helper documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/language_helper.html